# Cufon and Internet Explorer error

Tags: internet-explorer, cufon

i'm encountering an error on IE (both 7 & 8) related to cufon-yui.js
"The property or method are no supported by the object" Line 7, character 7725, of cufon-yui.js.

This is the last version of cufon (the one supported by IE 9) and i used it for other sites with no issues.

In this project, I'm also coding a bit of jquery by myself, including cufon functions, but I don't think that's the reason. The IE error refers to cufon core itself.

By now, I can't link you the site for privacy matters.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also encounter an error with cufon at line 7, this happens when I make a call to Cufon.replace() before the cufon-yui.js file has finished downloading.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of the cufon script works with IE9.  Make sure you have v1.09i or higher installed as some of the prior versions had some issues with various IE releases, especially IE9 beta.

Download from:
http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

Supporting documentation about this issue:
https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/faq#wiki-faq-1

Answer (score 0):

You might need the [Sizzle Selector](https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/faq) utility for IE, it works hand-in-hand with Cufon, as all of your replacements are non-basic strings (like `H2`, `li`).

So in this order:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sizzle/sizzle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon/cufon-yui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Script_400.font.js"></script>
</head>
```

then...

```
<body>
    <!-- other body contents in here... -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
            Cufon.now();
            Cufon.replace('#hd h2'); // Requires a selector engine for IE 6-7, hence 'sizzle.js' dependency
            Cufon.replace('h1,h2'); // Doesn't require selector engine
    </script>
</body>
```